# Changing a Defined Name Formula to VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a chart change its range dynamically in VBA. I have a defined name (named "Data") that gets the range very nicely but I want it translated into VBA to be able to distribute the macro.

Defined Name:

```
=OFFSET(Chart!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Chart!$A:$A)+1,COUNTA(Chart!$2:$2)+1)
```

VBA Code I have so far:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Data")
```

The code works with what I have so far, but I'm trying to find a way to not use the defined name.

> EDIT: I just recorded a macro of me adding the name and kept my code the same. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Why don't you just define the name in VBA?

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: @Aysee - to define a name in `VBA` simpy define name in Excel and record a macro.

Comment: Why not use the defined name? That's generally the way I work in VBA. Define the names through the UI, use the named ranges in VBA. It makes things tweakable in the frontend/UI without having to have the user dive into code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to define a range and to use it as source:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = [Data]

ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=myRange
```

Or you can pass the range "manually":

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Worksheets("MyNameIsSlim").Range("A1:B10")
```